# CronExpressionDescriptor and QuartzScheduler compatibility

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to find a correct way to schedule jobs on a weekly basis ( specific day ) , using quartz scheduler.
I also need to print the description of the cron job so I decided to use
CronExpressionDescriptor.getDescription() in order to enable non-programmers to read the expression's meaning.

However , when I'm using the cronExpression  - 0 15 3 ? * 2

CronExpressionDescriptor.getDescription() returns At 3:15 AM, only on ***Tuesday***

but when calling

```
trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity(triggerName, group.getGroupName()).withSchedule(cronSchedule(executionTime)).forJob(job.getKey()).build();      
Date date = scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

The date would be ***Monday*** (Mon Mar 03 03:15:00 EST 2015)

My current solution is to use

```
int dayOfWeek = (Integer.valueOf(cronexpression.split(" ")[5])%7);
trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity(triggerName, group.getGroupName()).withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.weeklyOnDayAndHourAndMinute(dayOfWeek, hour, minute)).forJob(job.getKey()).build();
```

but of course I don't like that solution as it's patchy and ugly. 
So my questions are :

1. Is there any correlation between quartz and CronExpressionDescriptor?
   Do you know other framework which is a able to return a human representation of cronExpression String.
2. Do you have a better solution?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The CronExpressionDescriptor for me is "more correct" that Quartz, because in linux cron schedules the "day-of-week" field ranges from 0-7, where 0 and 7 are equivalent to Sunday, then 2 equals Tuesday.

Quartz  ranges from 1-7 where 1 is Sunday and 7 is Saturday.

I don't know CronExpressionDescriptor, but, try search a way that returns a day name (SUN,MON, etc) instead day number representation.